# How to disable the character limit in swiftlint config file

Tags: ios, swift, swiftlint

I am working on a project and i need to how to disable the character limit in swiftlint config file , so how to disable the character limit ??

Here is the swiftlint file

```
disabled_rules:
  - force_cast
  - force_try
  - variable_name
  - type_name
  - file_length
  - type_body_length
  - cyclomatic_complexity
  - function_body_length
  - valid_docs
  - trailing_whitespace

opt_in_rules:
  - empty_string

excluded:
  - Carthage
  - Pods
  - SwiftLint/Common/3rdPartyLib

line_length:
    warning: 150
    error: 200
    ignores_function_declarations: true
    ignores_comments: true
    ignores_urls: true

custom_rules:
  smiley_face:
    name: "Smiley Face"
    regex: '( :\))'
    match_kinds:
      - comment
      - string
    message: "A closing parenthesis smiley :) creates a half-hearted smile, and thus is not preferred. Use :]"
severity: warning
```

Comment: `file_length` is already added, it should work, what character limit should be required?

Comment: actually the line character limit , i need to disable as it shows that line should be 150 characters or less

Comment: Can't you increase it to a very high limit?

Comment: No my maintainer asked me to disable the line character limit.

Comment: Well you have an answer below so what is the issue?

Comment: `line_length` limit set to `150` is pretty generous (even only 200 being a hard error!) and I cannot honestly imagine why anyone would want to turn it off completely. I am sure your maintainer is not very good. To be honest, when I look your disabled rules, I am not sure why you even use swiftlint at all.

Answer (score 6):

If you face some problem with this warning:

```
Identifier Name Violation: Variable name should be between 3 and 40 characters long: 'by' (identifier_name)
```

You can add these command to your configuration file:

```
variable_name:   
max_length:
    warning: 45
    error: 60   
min_length:
    warning: 1
```

I hope this helps you and fits with your question.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you can do it adding `line_length` inside `disabled_rules`, if that's what you mean.

Comment: Yes i need to disable the line character limit

Comment: So, as I said you only have to remove all what you currently have related to `line_length` and add `- line_length` inside your `disabled_rules`